# symfony2 @Assert\File empty in database

Tags: php, symfony, file-upload, symfony-2.7

I'm trying to upload an excel file in a symfony2 form, but without giving any errors, it's not inserting anything in this field. Other fields are filled in well in my database. Anyone has an idea?

I have a table files and a table orders with field delivery_list_id referring to the id of the file. At least, that's the idea.

Here is the entity part:

```
/**
 * @var File
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Myapp\Bundle\CoreBundle\Entity\File", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true)
 */
private $deliveryList;

/**
 * @var UploadedFile
 *
 * @Assert\File(
 *     mimeTypes = {"application/vnd.ms-excel", "application/vnd.ms-office", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", "text/plain", "text/csv", "application/octet-stream"},
 *     mimeTypesMessage = "The mime type of the file is invalid ({{ type }}). Allowed mime types are {{ types }}"
 * )
 */
private $uploadedDeliveryList;

/**
 * @return File
 */
public function getDeliveryList()
{
    return $this->deliveryList;
}

/**
 * @param File $deliveryList
 */
public function setDeliveryList($deliveryList)
{
    $this->deliveryList = $deliveryList;
}

/**
 * @return UploadedFile
 */
public function getUploadedDeliveryList()
{
    return $this->uploadedDeliveryList;
}

/**
 * @param UploadedFile $uploadedDeliveryList
 *
 * @return $this
 */
public function setUploadedDeliveryList($uploadedDeliveryList)
{
    $this->uploadedDeliveryList = $uploadedDeliveryList;

    return $this;
}
```

Here's the twig part:

```
$builder
                ->add('uploadedDeliveryList', 'bootstrap_file', array(
                    'initialCaption' => 'Please select an excelfile or csv file',
                    'file' => $order->getDeliveryList(),
                    'initialPreview' => ($order->getDeliveryList() ? '<a type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".preview_' . $order->getDeliveryList()->getId() . '"><img src="' . $this->router->generate('file_thumbnail', ['id' => $order->getDeliveryList()->getId()]) . '" alt="preview"></a>' : ''),
                    'label' => 'Upload a delivery list',
                    'attr' => array(
                        'class' => 'col-sm-12 file',
                        'accept' => 'application/vnd.ms-excel, application/vnd.ms-office, application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet, text/plain, text/csv, application/octet-stream'
                    ),
                    'required' => false,
                )
            );
```

My form has

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

Anyone has a clue why it's updating everything in my orders table, but not inserting the file in the files table (nor the delivery_list_id in my orders table)?

This is my upload handler, where he writes the file to the server, but doesn't do the database update. Even when the script passes there and no error is given.
If i set a die('in');, in my entity setDeliveryList, it seems it's not coming in there.

```
public function handleUploadedFiles(Event $event)
{
    $order = $event->getOrder();
    if ($uploadedDeliveryList = $order->getUploadedDeliveryList()) {
        $file = $this->transformUploadedFileToFile('/' . $order->getClient()->getId() . '/order/' . $order->getNumber() . '/deliverylist', $uploadedDeliveryList, $order->getDeliveryList());
        $file->setClient($order->getClient());
        $order->setDeliveryList($file);
    }
}
```

Comment: what is `bootstrap_file`? I believe you would need to change it to a [`File field`](https://symfony.com/doc/2.7/reference/forms/types/file.html). If you want to force a file to be uploaded, you may also need to add `@Assert\NotBlank`

Comment: Also please show your controller code, as this is where the form would be processed. You can check the Symfony Documentation on [How to Upload Files](https://symfony.com/doc/2.7/controller/upload_file.html) to ensure you are following best-practices

Comment: @fyrye it's with a bootstrap library, when i change it to just 'file' and change the attributes, i got the same problem

Comment: @fyrye i updated my question with my controller.

Comment: Check the rights on the upload directory.

Comment: I don't think there is enough info in your post to troubleshoot the issue. e.g. I don't see that you are moving the uploaded file to a non-temporary location or processing the `uploadedDeliveryList` from the entity/doctrine listener. See the Symfony [How to Upload Files](https://symfony.com/doc/2.7/controller/upload_file.html) controller example. Keep in mind that PHP deletes uploaded files [after the request has ended](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php#example-385). and Symfony does not save the blob to the database by default, only the path.

Comment: @fyrye i updated my question with more detailed info, like the upload handler and the getter and setters of my entity. Could you please have a look?

Comment: @JulienBourdic the file is saved successfully on the server, but it's not inserted in the db